# Min and max resistance of this network with potentiometer

Tags: resistors, thevenin, network

As the 20 kΩ pot is adjusted from A to B, any idea what the minimum and maximum Thévenin resistance is between C and D? Any thoughts on some equations?

[image]

Comment: Any thoughts on how you would approach finding a maximum here?

Comment: @periblepsis You bet I would. I'd split the $20K$ pot into two resisters, $R_top$ would be $X$ and $R_bottom$ would be $20-X$. Then I'd put $R_top$ in parallel with the $10K$ and call it $R_A$, then I'd put $R_bottom$ in parallel with the $15K$ and call that $R_B$. After that I'd call $R_total = R_A + R_B$ and start some algebra. Then I'd take the derivative of $R_total$ set it equal to zero to get the max.  -- That's how I'd approach it. Sound good?

Comment: It sounds perfect! Have you tried that? (Of course, there is a simplifying idea you could use to avoid the trouble. But that's for another time, I suppose.)

Comment: Oh yes. I went all the way with it. I posted this problem here hoping someone would surprise me with a shortcut. Verified the equations to entries in an Excel spreadsheet. Plotted the parabola and verified the results of my equations. So it's done, but is there a shorter way to solve it.

Comment: @periblepsis putting it into a spreadsheet and plotting it... to me... is the shortcut. Increment $X$ at 500 ohm jumps to get a good idea.

Comment: Well, if you take \$p\$ as the potentiometer position, with 0 being at the top and 1 being at the bottom, then the maximal setting is \$p=\frac1{1+\frac{15\:\text{k}}{10\:\text{k}}}=0.4\$. So the final peak resistance would be \$\frac{1}{\frac1{20\:\text{k}\Omega}+\frac{1}{10\:\text{k}\Omega+15\:\text{k}\Omega}}\$. You may see a clue about a simplifying view there.

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to go fiddle with this and see how it all comes together.

Comment: Steve, the clue here is that the optimal setting is when there is no wiper current!! When that happens all you have is the potentiometer in parallel with the series of the other two! And that will be the maximum resistance. Just imagine the potentiomater as another resister divider. When it is set so that the unloaded wiper voltage is the same as the other divider pair's voltage, then there will be no current between them. Do you see now? (Any imbalance will lower the resistance from that point.)

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of this but not sure why I didn't think like this in the first place. Va=Vb. Okay off I go into lessons learned once again.

Comment: Steve, just keep working on finding better mental models in your head. You start with one idea about resistance. But then there are better, more broadly useful and widely applicable ideas about resistance. Once you acquire the better one, you dump the older ones in favor of it. The older ones require half a dozen different but narrowly useful thoughts which clog your mind by so many bewildering choices to sort through. The single unifying idea takes a moment to grasp. But then you find the same one works in so many different ways.

Comment: Plot of resistance has been added

Answer (score 2):

As you suggested in the comments, the potentiometer is just two resistors in series, which I will call \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Wdv3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Total resistance \$R_T\$ between C and D is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_T &= (R_1 \parallel R_3) + (R_2 \parallel R_4) \\ \\
&= \frac{R_1 R_3}{R_1 + R_3} + \frac{R_2 R_4}{R_2 + R_4}
\end{aligned}
$$

I'll use a parameter \$x\$ to represent the potentiometer position, where \$0 \le x \le 1\$. That gives us the following relationships between \$R_P\$, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$:

$$ R_1 + R_2 = R_P $$
$$ R_1 = xR_P $$
$$ R_2 = (1-x)R_P $$

Plug those into the above equation:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_T &= \frac{xR_P R_3}{xR_P + R_3} + \frac{(1-x)R_P R_4}{(1-x)R_P + R_4} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

You could carry on and simplify that (not much, I'm afraid), or you could plug in the known values for \$R_P\$, \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$. That would yield an expression for \$R_T\$ purely in terms of \$x\$, which answers your question, what is \$R_T(x)\$.

Then, as you suggested in your own comment, you can find the derivative \$\frac{d(R_T)}{dx}\$, to reveal the maxima/minima, remembering of course that \$x\$ is only valid in the range \$0 \le x \le 1\$.

Comment: Solution was posted. Yours looks correct!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there isn't a wiper, for a moment. Or, in order words, all you have are two parallel branches. From the point of view **C** to **D**, the resistance will be the parallel resistance of the two branches, of course.

This must also be the maximum resistance.

Now, bring back in the wiper. But let's do so in just such a way that there is no wiper current. In other words, setting the wiper's position so that the voltage at the wiper is the exact same voltage as the node between the other branch's series resistor pair. This way, nothing is disturbed. It's exactly the same as before.

Now, what happens if the wiper is changed from this position? Well, it will either divert some current to the left or else to the right. But either way, this means that there is an *easier* path being presented. Not so? If so, then of course the resistance seen from **C** to **D** must decline.

So again the maximum point must occur when the wiper current is zero!

If you label things so that \$R_1=10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2=15\:\text{k}\Omega\$ then the optimal potentiometer position (with \$p=0\$ being at top and \$p=1\$ being at bottom) must be \$p=\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}}\$.

That sets the wiper current to zero. And at that point the resistance seen from **C** to **D** is just the parallel of the two branches, of course.

#### summary

As you wrote:

> I'd split the $20K$ pot into two resisters, $R_top$ would be $X$ and
> $R_bottom$ would be $20-X$. Then I'd put $R_top$ in parallel with the
> $10K$ and call it $R_A$, then I'd put $R_bottom$ in parallel with the
> $15K$ and call that $R_B$. After that I'd call $R_total = R_A + R_B$
> and start some algebra. Then I'd take the derivative of $R_total$ set
> it equal to zero to get the max. -- That's how I'd approach it. Sound
> good?

So you already completely understand the standard mathematical approach. Something like this:

```
def par(a,b): return a*b/(a+b)
rtotal = par( r1, p*rpot ) + par( r2, (1.0-p)*rpot )
solve( Eq( derivative( rtotal, p ), 0 ), p )[0]
r1/(r1 + r2)
```

Which solves for \$p\$, quite as you said it would.

But you still also wisely wrote:

> I'm aware of this but not sure why I didn't think like this in the
> first place. Va=Vb.

That's the insight that solves the problem without the math. It's also an important insight that goes beyond algebra.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it as a maximization problem.

Let the upper part of the Potentiometer be \$R\$, then the lower part is (\$20-R\$), all in \$k\Omega\$.

The resistance between \$C\$ and \$D\$ is then,
$$R_{TH} = \frac{10R}{10+R} + \frac{15(20-R)}{15+20-R}$$

Maximize that function (find \$R\$ for zero derivative), you reach:
$$R = 8 \,\,k\Omega$$
and
$$R_{TH} = \frac{100}{9} \approx 11.1 \,\,k\Omega$$

Comment: min value should be 6.667K not 8K

Comment: I didn't say that min value is 8K ! Read my answer carefully

Comment: Gotcha!  Maximize that function (find R for zero derivative), you reach:
R=8kΩ

Comment: 8K? Where does 8K come from?  I get 12K produces 11.111K Or am I missing something? Look at my solution and the excel data.

Comment: Never mind. I see where you got 8k. Good job

Answer (score 0):

First some calculus

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x || y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{xy}{x+y}\right) = \frac{(x+y)y-xy}{(x+y)^2} = \frac{y^2}{(x+y)^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f(x) || y) = \frac{y^2f'(x)}{(f(x)+y)^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} ((A-x) || y) = \frac{-y^2}{(A-x+y)^2}$$

Now, consider the following resistor network with resistances A-x, x, B, and C.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVfHaR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The total resistance is

$$R_T=((A-x) || B) + (x || C)$$

we would like to know if there are any values of \$0 \le x \le A\$ such that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(((A-x) || B) + (x || C)\right) = 0$$

or equivalently

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}((A-x) || B) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x || C)$$

Calculating, we seek x such that

$$\frac{-B^2}{(A-x+B)^2} = -\frac{C^2}{(x+C)^2}$$

$$B^2(x+C)^2 = C^2(A-x+B)^2$$

This has two solutions.

$$x = \frac{AC}{B+C} \;\;\text{or}\;\; x=\frac{AC+2BC}{C-B}$$

Making the following assignments

$$A=20$$
$$B=10$$
$$C=15$$

We find possible solutions for x as

$$x = \frac{(20)(15)}{(10+15)} = 12$$

or

$$x = \frac{(20)(15)+2(10)(15)}{15-10} = 120$$

we reject the latter possibility because it is greater than A=20.

We now look at x=0, x=12, and x=20.

When x=0, we have R = (A || B) = (20 || 10) = 200/30 = 6.666

When x=A, we have R = (20 || 15) = 300/35 = 8.57

We get the following values for \$R_T\$

$$R_T = 6.666, 11.111, 8.57$$

So, the *minimum* resistance is 6.667 k\$\Omega\$ which occurs when the wiper is at 0 k\$\Omega\$ wiper to bottom, and the *maximum* resistance is 11.1111 k\$\Omega\$ which occurs when the wiper is at 12 k \$\Omega\$ wiper to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The blue arching parabola is the plot of the resistance as the pot is adjusted from A to B. You can use the shortcut method offered by @periblepsis ... or you can use equations and take the derivative. You can also use Excel to plot the curve in 250 ohm increments.

[image]

[image]

Excel Data:

[image]

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy No, Steve's got it correct. The other number should be 8571.42857142857 Ohms.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I added Excel data.

Comment: @steveK What is the formula you used?

Comment: @steveK my bad.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Sorry.. haha ... just pasted it in there.